# Search Bar not triggering when inputting text

Tags: react-native, ecmascript-6

I am trying to get my search bar to function, but it will not filter anything when I input text in it. Could somebody look at the code and tell me what may be the issue? All the items that are being displayed in the directory is data that is being pulled from a JSON folder I created. For space reasons, I took out all the elements/libraries I imported.

```
const items = [
  { name: "Homer Simpson", screen: "HomerSimpson" },
  { name: "Marge Simpson", screen: "MargeSimpson" },
  { name: "Bart Simpson", screen: "BartSimpson" },
  { name: "Lisa Simpson", screen: "LisaSimpson" },
  { name: "Maggie Simpson", screen: "MaggieSimpson" }
];

class CharacterDirectory extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: []
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      data: items
    });
  }
  updateSearch(search) {
    var data = items.filter(item =>
      item.name.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase())
    );
    this.setState({ data });
  }
  render() {
    const { navigation } = this.props;
    const type = navigation.getParam("itemID", "NO-ID");
    const typeData = characters[type];
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <ImageBackground
          source={{
            uri:
              "https://backgrounddownload.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/simpsons-clouds-background-5.jpg"
          }}
          style={{
            width: "100%",
            height: "100%",
            alignContent: "center",
            justifyContent: "center",
            alignItems: "center"
          }}
        >
          <SearchHeader
            updateSearch={search => {
              this.updateSearch(search);
            }}
          />
          {characters.map((data, index) => (
            <Button
              text={data.name}
              key={data.name}
              title={`${data.name}`}
              onPress={() => {
                this.props.navigation.navigate("CharacterProfiles", {
                  item: data
                });
              }}
            />
          ))}
        </ImageBackground>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
export default withNavigation(CharacterDirectory);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this code

```
{characters.map((data, index) => (
            <Button
              text={data.name}
              key={data.name}
              title={`${data.name}`}
              onPress={() => {
                this.props.navigation.navigate("CharacterProfiles", {
                  item: data
                });
              }}
            />
          ))}
```

to this code

```
{this.state.data.map((data, index) => (
            <Button
              text={data.name}
              key={data.name}
              title={`${data.name}`}
              onPress={() => {
                this.props.navigation.navigate("CharacterProfiles", {
                  item: data
                });
              }}
            />
          ))}
```

Comment: Thanks!  It works, but now for some reason, I am getting a message that there are two children with the same key as a warning message.  When I start searching, after I am done, it somehow adds more buttons to the screen.  Any reason why it is doing that now?

Comment: Warning will be removed when you use "key={index}" instead of "key={data.name}"